# Should i use Same HttpUrlconnection or define each time a new one?

Tags: java

I am using HttpUrlConnect to post data to a webservice .
This posting of data will happen , whenever there is any logging event called .(so this is continous)

I have a question with respect to this , should i use the same HttpURLConnection as shown below

```
private HttpURLConnection getConnection() throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RestTest/ajax/user_info");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        return conn;
    }

    public void execute() throws Exception {
        OutputStream os = null;
        try {

            HttpURLConnection conn = null;


            conn = getConnection();

            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

            String input = "{\\\"qty\\\":100,\\\"name\\\":\\\"sdsfds ddd\\\"}";

            os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            conn.getInputStream();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }

        }

    }
```

Or should i define connection everythime as shown below ??

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
        OutputStream os = null;
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/RestTest/ajax/user_info");

            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            String input = "{\\\"qty\\\":100,\\\"name\\\":\\\"sdsfds ddd\\\"}";
            os = conn.getOutputStream();
            os.write(input.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            conn.getInputStream();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            conn.disconnect();
            if (os != null) {
                os.close();
            }

        }

    }
```

Please tell me what is appropiate in this context ??

Comment: You *can't* use the same one each time. You get a new one every time you call `URL.openConnection()`. Both your code excerpts do the same thing. Not a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)'s javadoc says:

> **Each HttpURLConnection instance is used to make a single request** but the underlying network connection to the HTTP server may be transparently shared by other instances.

So, although in the background the connection could be the same, you should use a new intance per request.